# Java Jackson- Compare two JSONs ignoring order of keys and elements in arrays

Tags: java, jackson

I have two JSON strings which I want to compare.
I want neither the order of the keys to matter or the order of elements in an array.
However I do want an extra field to be considered "not equal"

Non strict mode with JSONAssert seems like it fits the bill except for an extra field being considered equal "http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/cookbook.html"

If at all possible I would like to avoid pulling in extra dependancies. I already have jackson in my project

Comment: I'd parse both to become JsonNodes, and write the recursive comparison myself (a little exercise in algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ideas how to do it.

1. Is to write java objects and serialize it, and write own equals method.
2. Is to serialize it to Map<Object, Object> and compare 2 map.

```
        String json1 = "{...}"
        String json2= "{...}"
        Object json1Object = objectMapper.readValue(json1, Object.class);
        Object json2Object = objectMapper.readValue(json2, Object.class);
        Assertions.assertEquals(json1Object, json2Object);

        Assertions.assertTrue(json1Object.equals(json2Object));
```

Comment: That wont work for collections. [2,1] is not equal to [1,2] when using .equals. I am also trying to avoid writing .equals for java methods. Its the reason I am comparing using JSON. I am comparing a very complex object with lots of different nested objects, and writing .equals for all the objects required is a problem

Answer (score 0):

So you probably have only one option. Write own comparator.
My quick solution:

```
    @Test
    public void comparingJsonTest4() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json1 = "{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"test\", \"cars\": [\"Ford\", \"BMW\", \"Fiat\"]}";
        String json2 = "{\"name\": \"test\", \"id\": 1, \"cars\": [\"BMW\", \"Ford\", \"Fiat\"]}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode json1Node = objectMapper.readTree(json1);
        JsonNode json2Node = objectMapper.readTree(json2);

        Assertions.assertEquals(0, new ComparatorWithoutOrder().compare(json1Node, json2Node));
    }

    class ComparatorWithoutOrder implements Comparator<JsonNode> {

        @Override
        public int compare(JsonNode o1, JsonNode o2) {
            if(o1 == o2) {
                return 0;
            }
            if(o1.getClass() != o2.getClass()) {
                return -1;
            }
            if(o1.getClass() == ObjectNode.class) {
                List<String> o1FieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
                o1.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(o1FieldNames::add);
                List<String> o2FieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
                o2.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(o2FieldNames::add);
                if(o1FieldNames.size() != o2FieldNames.size()) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if(!o2FieldNames.containsAll(o1FieldNames) || !o1FieldNames.containsAll(o2FieldNames)) {
                    return -1;
                }
                for (String o1FieldName : o1FieldNames) {
                    if (!(compare(o1.get(o1FieldName), o2.get(o1FieldName)) == 0)) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
            if(o1.getClass() == ArrayNode.class) {
                List<JsonNode> o1Children = new ArrayList<>();
                o1.elements().forEachRemaining(o1Children::add);
                List<JsonNode> o2Children = new ArrayList<>();
                o2.elements().forEachRemaining(o2Children::add);
                if(o1Children.size() != o2Children.size()) {
                    return -1;
                }
                for (JsonNode c1 : o1Children) {
                    boolean found = false;
                    for (JsonNode c2 : o2Children) {
                        if (compare(c1, c2) == 0) {
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!found) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                return 0;

            }
            return o1.equals(o2) ? 0 : -1;
        }
    }
```

At the beginning I wanted to use something like this:

```
json1Node.equals(new ComparatorWithoutOrder(), json2Node);
```

but thre was a problem to propoer handle ArrayNode inside ObjectNode. So if you want, you could skip `implements Comparator<JsonNode>`, because finally I don't use this functionality.